# Convert Nancy.DynamicDictionaryValue to specified object?

Tags: c#, dynamic, nancy

I'm having some trouble with Nancy because I want to get specified objects back from the query string, instead of Nancy.DynamicDictionaryValue.

For instance, if I make a request such as: http://localhost:8080/foo?name=x&width=10&height=10

I would get a DynamicDictionary back from Nancy, and all of the values from the query string would be of type Nancy.DynamicDictionaryValue.

Is it possible to somehow get them back as string, int etc... And would I get in more trouble if I wanted more complex data types?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just cast it, it's a dynamic type and it will convert (or attempt to) to whatever type you cast it to, or you can just pass it directly into a method that takes a specific type and it will do it then.

You can also use the modelbinding if you want an object with those properties in it, just create an object with ah X, Width and Height property and do this.Bind();

Comment: If I have an object that has properties x, y, z, and more, can I do this.Bind() if I only receive properties x, y, z, from the query string? And also I don't need to specify any params in this.Bind?

Comment: @JSarwer all you need to do is `var things = this.Bind<MyObject>();` and you will get an object composed of data available from Routes, Query String, and Body. If the values come from the query string and there's no route/body info, then you will only get the query string values.